# How to prevent being cut off a remote machine after a misconfiguration of a firewall playbook

Tags: firewall, ansible, ufw

Despite being careful, such a situation can happen and can be very toilsome to fix.

Answer (score 6):

A solution is to register a command using the [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) utility that will disable the firewall completely after a timeout period. And if the playbook successfully proceeds past the end, the command is cancelled.

The example below uses [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), but it can be adapted to any other service.

```yaml
- name: Install package ufw
  apt:
    name: [at, ufw]
    state: present

- block:
  - name: Make sure to disable the firewall later if something goes wrong
    ansible.posix.at:
      command: "{{ firewall_disable_ufw }}"
      count: 3
      units: minutes
    changed_when: false

  # All tasks that modify the firewall go in here.

  - name: Cancel the above safety firewall disable command
    ansible.posix.at:
      command: "{{ firewall_disable_ufw }}"
      state: absent
    changed_when: false

  rescue:
    - fail:
        msg: >-
          WARNING: Task '{{ ansible_failed_task.name }}' failed.
          Firewall will be disabled soon by an `at` command
          `{{ firewall_disable_ufw }}`
  vars:
    firewall_disable_ufw: "systemctl disable --now ufw.service"
```

Using `block:` / `rescue:` isn't really necessary, but provides a nice visual demarcation of the whole block and a better error message if the playbook fails.